# Typing on an EditText without disturbing ongoing activity?

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

So I am making a sticky note sorta thing that always appears on top and user can press on it to type on it. So here is my working code:

```
 mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE); 
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
 (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 myView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.notepad, null ); //notepad.xml contains the EditText

  WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
  mWindowManager.addView(myView, params);
```

The problem is that when I use the flag TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, I can't get focus to type on the EditText. Alternate would be to use TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT and I can use the EditText to type on, but then the entire background would freeze. How can I allow the user to type without interrupting background activity (aka game, video, scrolling thru Facebook etc)

Comment: This is no easy task look for a library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an opensource library for that. Its called the standOut library. Have a [look.](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut/tree/master/library)

[image]

It may help you.